# Stuck in infinite loop of authentication when trying to commit changes to google code

Tags: svn, google-code

I'm attempting to commit to [a project hosted on google code](http://code.google.com/p/mangoblog/) that I am not the owner of, but [do have commit rights to](http://code.google.com/p/mangoblog/people/list). I have done so in the past, but with a different client (Subclipse). I'm not sure if the problem is something I'm doing wrong, a shortcoming of the client I'm using, or a temporary issue on Google's end.

When I attempt to commit using [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/), I get a dialog requesting my password. I know I'm typing it carefully, slowly, and correctly; but the dialog seems to come back up endlessly. I also tried committing via the command line and got the same result:

```
$ svn commit "/Users/adam/Documents/Adobe ColdFusion Builder workspace/Mango-Official/src/coldfusion/application/admin/setup/setup.cfm" -m "Added functionality to remove the setup folder after install is complete, to help improve security" --username "j.adam.tuttle"
Authentication realm: <https://mangoblog.googlecode.com:443> Google Code Subversion Repository
Password for 'j.adam.tuttle': 
Authentication realm: <https://mangoblog.googlecode.com:443> Google Code Subversion Repository
Username: j.adam.tuttle
Password for 'j.adam.tuttle': 
Authentication realm: <https://mangoblog.googlecode.com:443> Google Code Subversion Repository
Username: ^C
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/!svn/act/5a28cb41-a508-41bd-bf85-3c0a3f1d4337': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://mangoblog.googlecode.com)
```